# Why is can i not use a conditional property where a string should be?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, variables

I was trying to do something where the email recipient of an email compose controller changes based on an @property variable. I tried multiple ways to achieve the desired result but none of them worked, i have listed the code i used & the errors i was getting. I would be extremely grateful for any replies!

```
[self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:email]];
```

"Missing sentinel in method dispatch" & The App crashes saying the following error message: "Unknown class De in Interface Builder file."

```
[self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"%d", email]];
```

"Missing sentinel in method dispatch" & The App crashes saying the following error message: "Unknown class De in Interface Builder file."

I am not sure what the problem is but it always seems to crash only when i add those variable strings, when i add a hard coded email address.

I would appreciate any replies :)

Kind Regards,

Coconido

Comment: What kind of variable is email?

Comment: You're also not `nil`-terminating your array properly when using `arrayWithObjects`

Comment: I created the property like this: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *emailAddress;

Comment: I changed it to this & it didn't change anything Stonz2: [self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:email, nil]];

Comment: Try doing this instead for testing purposes: [self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:@[@"test@msn.com"]]; Does that work?

Comment: Yes that works as well but what do i do to put the email property in there?

Comment: Fer cryin out loud -- read the spec for `arrayWithObjects`.

Comment: The crash that you describe is unrelated to the warning and to this line of code. This question is pretty much impossible to edit into a state of being useful for others; you need to learn how to do some debugging on your own, in particular how to isolate problems. Please read through "[My app crashed! Now what?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)" in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here, so it's probably a combination of problems. Based on the comments it's likely email is a UILabel property, not an NSString

The easiest way to create an NSArray in Objective-C is the following syntax:

```
@[someObject, anotherObject, aThirdObject]
```

Thus, in your case, you want to do this:

```
[self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:@[email.text]];
```

The above will work if email is a UILabel object with the actual email address as the text inside it. ***My guess is that the email object is a label and not text like you think.***

Also on a side note, it seems like when you did this:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"%d", email]
```

.. you had something like this in mind:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", email]
```

Note the differences in the second example, it uses %@ instead of %d. %d is used to format decimal values, whereas %@ would be used for object formatting. In this case, using a single string inside the string formatting would be a little pointless, but you get the idea.

Comment: That gives me the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel mf_isLegalCommentedEmailAddress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: add this line of code before you setToRecipients and tell me what get logged: NSLog(@"class: ", [email class]);

Comment: It says "Data argument not used to format string" and i don't think it is working because it always crashes.

Comment: oh no sorry do this: NSLog(@"class: %@", [email class])

Comment: 2014-07-16 23:02:43.958 PressNet[1875:60b] Unknown class De in Interface Builder file.
2014-07-16 23:02:47.255 PressNet[1875:60b] <UILabel: 0x175d3f70; frame = (0 342; 320 30); text = 'test@test.com'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x175d4020>>
2014-07-16 23:02:47.259 PressNet[1875:60b] hello is not a valid email address.

Comment: Go into XCode and look here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxb96i3i48y6a4c/Screenshot%202014-07-16%2018.04.55.png Do you see "De" in the "custom class" section? It looks like maybe you added something there by accident?

Comment: No i see DetailViewController which is the custom class i set for it :/

Comment: You definitely have something in your app trying to reference "De", a typo or something in an interface builder file.

Comment: But would that be relevant because no issue arises if i don't do this property thing

Comment: Yes it would. This is almost certainly your problem. "Email" is not a string like you think it is. Can you show where you create the variable email? Edit your question with the code or info.

Comment: Also, you said email is a property.. A property on what?

Comment: I found the part where it says "De" it is a link to the view but it does not let me delete it... https://www.mediafire.com/?mszs030eq3kxrm8

Comment: So I see another issue, email is a label. If you want to add the text from the email use this instead: email.text (see my edited answer)

Comment: I could try chainging it to be:  [self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:@[email.text]];

Comment: Yes, try that. The issue with the DE thing may or may not be related, but you definitely want to clean that issue up because something is happening there that causes the app to crash because its trying to find a view named "DE" that doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems to have worked but now i don't know what to do if i want to get rid of the label, i guess i can just make the label invisible as a quick solution

Comment: If that fixed your problem, please vote/accept my answer as the solution, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote answers up but i will as soon as i do haha. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: ok, you should be able to accept it as the answer though. glad to help!